# Model Theory problem

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Good afternoon. I need some help with this little problem. I hope somebody could help me. Thanks a lot

Assume that $A\equiv B$. Then there exists a $C$ such that $A\prec C$ and $B\prec C$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hardly the afternoon for me, but here's a hint: use compactness theorem (if $A\subseteq C$, what does it mean that $A\preceq C$? Try to express it as $C\models T$ for some theory $T$).

As JDH suggested, $A\preceq C$ and $B\preceq C$ in the sense that $A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq C$ is not always possible for simple reason that as sets $A\cap B$ may be somewhat different than we would expect from two elementary substructures of $C$ (for example, if $C$ has a constant symbol and $A\cap B=\emptyset$). But there is always a $C$ into which $A,B$ can be elementarily embedded.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is false, if by $A\prec C$ you mean that $A$ is an elementary substructure of $C$. For example, suppose that there is a constant symbol in the language, which is interpreted in $A$ as a different object than in $B$. So they cannot both be elementary substructures of a single structure $C$, since all substructures of $C$ will interpret that constant symbol in the same way.

But if by $A\prec C$ you mean that $A$ embeds elementarily into $C$, that is, that $A$ is isomorphic to an elementary substructure of $C$, then you should follow the hints of tomasz.

Comment: You're right, but that's really set-theoretical nitpicking... still, good point. ;)

Comment: I don't think it is nitpicking, since this is the standard meaning of $A\prec C$.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but in model theory, we usually assume that every model is actually an elementary submodel of a fixed monster model, an in particular definable sets intersect the way they should. Of course, at such a basic level as this question this is a perfectly valid point. Maybe I'm a little too accustomed to the categorical viewpoint...

Comment: I don't think a "categorical" viewpoint forces one to miss the distinction between elementary substructure and elementary embeddability. These are simply distinct concepts, and I believe that $A\prec C$ is almost universally used to refer to elementary substructure, while elementary embeddability is usually denoted by $A\precsim B$ or something similar.

Comment: From categorical viewpoint the inclusion mapping is just a map, not distinguishable from any conjugate mapping from an isomorphic copy, so $A\subseteq C$ and $A\cap B$ don't really have a meaning in the category of models with elementary functions.  We do not concern ourselves with particular elements and "implementations" (indeed, we do not concern ourselves with most things that are not a problem up to isomorphism), so problems like this don't arise. That's what I meant. I never questioned your reading the meaning of $\prec$, I have written quite clearly that yours is a valid point, no?

Comment: That is not a correct description of the categorical viewpoint, which is perfectly capable of formalizing the concept of elementary substructure (but you need to be in the right category). Your over-simplified view would lead one to think that all automorphism groups are trivial, consisting only of the identity map (since they are all isomorphisms after all).